# EF4 code only - How do I change column order?

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first

I setup the builder and used CreateDatabase to generate the database.

However the table columns created are ordered alphabetically. Is there a way to control the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, code only doesn't have support to such feature.

**Edit:** The new CTP5 has an attribute called ColumnAttribute with some features like Order.

Hope it helps.